# Is there a way to generate names on top of a sprite?

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, hud

I'm a beginner in java and I'm using libgdx. Currently, I've followed a youtube guide to create a simple mario game and tweaked it into a 2 player game. However, is there a method to generate a name on top of a player to identify which player is which? Right now, what I did was edit the texture to add the player name, but that isn't the best way. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Your question is very vague and needs details. We cannot know how you implemented it and what was used. Try to do this yourself and make your question more specific by showing where you are stuck (through code).

Comment: Use the Label class. You can actually use it without Stage by calling `draw` on it directly. You will need to create a bitmap font and put it in a Skin to use with the Label, as explained in the Scene2D documentation.